Cookie stripped from request sent to Visual Studio Dev Tunnel from react-native
I have a react-native app that talks to a backend .NET web api.
I'm trying to get the Android emulator to be able to call into my web api instance running in the debugger.
I tried using the ip address 10.0.2.2 as most of the answers on google say, but that just fails with a generic network error. Nothing I tried was working except for a Dev Tunnel.
After creating a Dev Tunnel in Visual Studio, it is working from my Android emulator. It gets to my breakpoint in my web api project.
The problem is the Cookie is being stripped from the request.
When sending the request from react-native, it has the Cookie on the request containing auth tokens.
When inspecting the request received in Visual Studio debugger, it is missing the Cookie.
This all works perfectly when using the deployed web api service over the internet. It is only stripped when trying to call into the debugger using a Dev Tunnel.
Is there something about the way Dev Tunnels handle cookies? Has anyone seen this before? I couldn't find any answers to this specifically when googling.

Well, I was able to finally figure out the problem here, so I'll answer my own question and hopefully it will help someone else in the future.
It was actually caused by the way react-native works with cookies. Just adding this to the axios request caused the cookies to be included:
   withCredentials: false,
This was where this came from if anyone is looking for more context on the issues with react-native and cookies based auth:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23185#issuecomment-1148130842
